# How to define a class with same name as built-in function?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I would like to define a class named "List" like this:

```
class List
{
}
```

PHP gives the following error at the file of the class definition: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LIST, expecting T_STRING"

Apparently there is a php built-in function named "list()" that the parser is reading here instead of my class definition even though the line starts with the keyword **class**

Since I don't use the built-in function anywhere in my project I would like to "remove/disable" it, so I can use my class named "List".

Is this possible in php and how?

Comment: I think it is not possible, and if it would I don't override that function (or anyone other one). I bet that, as list is a generic name, you can find a better name easily. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`list` is a reserved word as it is a language construct (not actually a function), so no, you cannot disable it.  Try being more specific with your class name, e.g., `ObjectList` or `AbstractList`.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but probably the right thing to do. :) I went with naming it "Collection" which sort of serves the same purpose. I'm after a "generic list" type of object.

Comment: Then why not use `class GenericList`?  `Collection` works, too, I guess.

Comment: Just FYI: defining the class in a namespace won't work either, since it's a parse thing. You also can't name your methods `list`. Luckily you can name your vars `$list` =) I'm not sure about constants...

Comment: I had the same issue. Because the reserved word is 'list' not 'List' I expected the name 'List' to be a valid class name.

Comment: @Kwebble Class names (amongst other things) are case-insensitive in PHP, so `List` as a class name is the same as `list`.

Answer (score 6):

> The class name can be any valid label which is a not a PHP **reserved
>   word**.

[List of PHP reserved words](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) says `list` is one of those words.